# DNS lookup of custom url taking lot of time(5 sec) in android

Tags: android, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain registered with godaddy but I have the DNS servers in route 53.

When I am trying to ping the website through my android app the DNS resolution is taking 5 sec at the first time(after every 10 min). This is not the case with iOS or in mac browser, and when I am trying to hit the url from postman. This is happening only in my android app.

Solutions tried:

1) Tried in different phones,

2) Tried with different networks.

Trace of the time taken:
    REQUEST 1 (new connection)

```
0.000 callStart

0.007 dnsStart

5.048 dnsEnd

5.049 connectStart

5.056 secureConnectStart

5.106 secureConnectEnd

5.108 connectEnd

5.109 connectionAcquired

5.110 requestHeadersStart

5.112 requestHeadersEnd

5.196 responseHeadersEnd

5.197 responseBodyStart

REQUEST 1 (new connection) end success
```

It would be great help if you can help me out here.

Edit: adding code

```
String url = "https://customurl/";
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .eventListener(new PrintingEventListener())
            .dns(DnsSelector.byName("ipv6"))
            .build();
Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).client(httpClient)
            .build();
System.out.println("Scanning REQUEST 1 (new connection) url: " + url);

TestInterface testInterface = client.create(TestInterface.class);

Call<ResponseBody> testCall = testInterface.testCall();
Log.i( TAG, "Scanning apiCall Start");
testCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.i( TAG, "Scanning apiCall end success");
}

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i( TAG, "Scanning apiCall end failed");
        }});
```

Its very fast in android emulator
0.000 callStart

0.010 dnsStart

0.095 dnsEnd

0.096 connectStart

0.103 secureConnectStart

0.537 secureConnectEnd

0.563 connectEnd

0.565 connectionAcquired

0.567 requestHeadersStart

0.572 requestHeadersEnd

0.573 responseHeadersStart

0.733 responseHeadersEnd

0.739 responseBodyEnd

0.740 connectionReleased

0.740 callEnd

Comment: *＋1* for asking a DNS question that has to do with programming and development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround. I tried this solution earlier before posting but for some reason it didn't work then.

I added a public DNS resolver as mentioned [here](https://garage.easytaxi.com/tag/dns-android-okhttp/)

This brought down the dns lookup tie from 5.5 sec to 300 ms. Though this is still high from my perspective, but it's much better.